# Ant deployment error: Unknown user permission: ManagePartnerNetConn

Tags: profile, ant

I got below error during deployment of the profiles. Anyone know what this permission is? Note: in both source and target sandboxes I enabled communities.

Meanwhile I removed this permission manually from the XMl and it solved the issues, but I don't want to do it every time after fetching the profiles from SF.

Ant deployment error:

1. profiles/Admin.profile -- Error: Unknown user permission: ManagePartnerNetConn

Comment: In the org is there anything exist named as "ManagePartnerNetConn"?

Comment: Not something that I found in the setup...

Comment: Any permission set with this name???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure Salesforce to Salesforce is enabled in the target org.

Comment: Hi Quy, welcome to SFSE. Could you flesh out this answer with explanation of what this permission is/does, and perhaps share a documentation reference?

Comment: I just check it and Quy right. After enabling Salesforce to Salesforce seems it adding this permission in the profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to **Salesforce Classic** before enabling **Salesforce to Salesforce**
From Setup, enter **Salesforce to Salesforce Settings** in the Quick Find box, then select Salesforce to Salesforce Settings.
Click Edit.
Select Enable.
Click Save.

Comment: How this answer is different from the one, that was already accepted almost 5 years ago?

Comment: It lacked the clarity that it deserved